# Unreal c++ AddControllerYawInput() function working

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Can someone explain the ***AddControllerYawInput()*** function to me, What it does and How it is supposed to move the camera.  [Here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/APawn/AddControllerYawInput/index.html) is the link to the function on unreal docs. It doesn't explain the function that much and i am unable to find a satisfactory explanation too.

I am actually trying to move the camera attached to a pawn that i am controlling. According to unreal [HERE](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Tutorials/FirstPersonShooter/2/4/index.html) on this page, "AddControllerYawInput" should move my camera attached to my pawn (or i'm as usual mistaking it) but the camera doesn't move. I'm not completely noob at unreal. Anyone answering this question please first explain this function before telling me how to move that camera.(I can do this with other methods, i just want to know why the method on unreal docs isn't working and i also want to know about the function.)

---

***Thank You***.

Comment: Unreal Engine is open source, why don't you simply open the source file and see what it does?

Comment: @BasinhetVeld I just did that but still didn't understand why the method mentioned on unreal docs isn't working. That's why i asked, if someone has more clear concepts on this topic.